# NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/wsspi/uow/UOWException

Tags: migration, websphere, wildfly-10

We are migrating from WebSphere 8.0 to WildFly 10.0.0. after compiling the project in eclipse and removing all the reference of IBM WebSphere jars, on deploying the application, I am getting an error that `NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/wsspi/uow/UOWException` 
I have tried to search this exception class in my project, i did not find any.
Can you please help me in fixing this error.

Along with the migration , we are also upgrading Java version to 8 and Spring version to 4.3.0

Answer (score 0):

While working on this, I figured that we were referring to **WebSphereUowTransactionManager** which is specific for WebSphere in the Springs Transaction Manager. We have to replace it with **JtaTransactionManager** for removing the exception.